# Where's the "d" key on vim adventures level 5?

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm playing https://vim-adventures.com and cannot find the "d" key on level 5. It says it's in the word island but mine is the same as it was before. I know I need to do dw later but I can't find the "d" to start with!

Answer (score 1):

The key mentioned in the red text is not the key 'd'. You'll get 'd' from the text left of this, the one that tells how to use d. You can complete that one with the keys you have from earlier